# How to add multiple tap/tun, as I want to install multiple OpenVPN instance on one machine?

Tags: openvpn

I want to install multiple OpenVPN instance on one machine(Centos), and it seems that each instance needs a unique subnet, and how to do this? And how to install multiple tap/tun

Answer (score 3):

The subnet part is pretty straightforward, your "--server" directive lists the subnet involved:

http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html

There are a bunch of things you need to do when running multiple instances, see this page:

http://www.imped.net/oss/misc/openvpn-2.0-howto-edit.html

(search for "multiple OpenVPN instances")

I don't think you have to do anything special to create the tun1 device I think OpenVPN does it for you on CentOS but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Thanks, I found openvpn --mktun could create a new tun adapter, and which could solve this problem, thanks.